# Self-grounding clip

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, grounding

If a receptacle has a self-grounding clip and is being installed in a metal box, but the metal box does not have ground, does the clip itself provide ground?

Comment: How would it provide a ground?

Comment: That is my question exactly. In other words, does the fact that it is "self-grounding" provide ground, or does the metal box already have to have ground. I am unsure what the feature means.
My assumption is that the self-grounding clip eliminates the need to have a grounding wire directly connected to the receptacle.

Comment: About not needing a ground wire to the receptacle on a grounded box, you are right.

Comment: The clip implies that the connection between the screw and a metal box (or a plastic box with a metal strap, which are more common in Canada) is a bond. You "bond" all grounding conductors together, which need to make a path back to the ground used by your panel. If the box isn't grounded it won't ground. If the box is grounded by a ground wire terminated on its screw, or through metal conduit, the bonded device will be grounded.

Answer (score 4):

No.  The clip is just to make better contact with a grounded box.

If the box is not grounded by a ground wire or metal conduit it is just a box.

A simple test to see if the box is grounded, is to use a multi meter between hot and box.  A grounded box should read ~120 volts, an ungrounded box should read 0 volts.

Comment: If it is not grounded, i assume i should probably install a GFCI?

Comment: Some locations require a GFCI more, but it does not hurt to install one anyway and be safe.  Locations near sinks, outside, basements/garages all require them these days on new circuits(recommended to add them on old circuits).

Answer (score 1):

NO.

A ground wire can be attached to the metal box to then make it grounded.

The metal box must be grounded, or you must attach the ground wire directly to the receptacle or switch. Once screwed to the box, the box is then grounded.

If there is no ground wire available, to attain a ground, a new wire must be run.